# Handle a request from multiple methods

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm currently working on a spring-boot application. I have my custom user data stored in a repository. Usually I attach the user data in every Controller (this is needed if a user is authenticated). But if I enter a unmapped URL the data will logically not be passed and my error 404 page will not load correctly.

I can't just use

```
@RequestMapping(value="**",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAnythingelse(){
    return "redirect:/404.html";
}
```

because I handle my urls spread apon different controller classes.

That leads to to asking how can i solve this?

I would have two theoretical attempts, but i don't know how i would do that:
1) Somehow give the map-anything method very low priority, so it will get called at the end.
2) Call the map-anything method, butsome how make the system call the other methods as well.

EDIT: Even if i add it to e.g. my index controller, it will make the site completely unformated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a DefaultController to your project and use RequestMapping annotation top of that. I tried this piece of code:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="**")
public class DefaultController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAnythingElse(){
        return "redirect:/404.html";
    }

}
```

I think it does exactly what you want, but in my case it interrupts my swagger-ui.

Comment: This will not work for `@RestController` but for `@Controller` only.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help you to achieve your custom error page : 
https://gist.github.com/jonikarppinen/662c38fb57a23de61c8b